# State Machine Capable of All Transitions

Tags: state-machine

I am trying to design a state machine which will traverse all possible transitions between states. However, the state machine cannot move from a given state back to itself. From the diagram below, I have worked out that given the number of states (N), the number of transitions is equal to N^2 - N.

[image: State Transitions for 5 States]

Any ideas on how to approach this please?

Comment: You want to implement this?

Comment: Yes, I have a 5 bit pattern that I want to send to a device will all possible transitions ie. 32 states with 992 transitions

Comment: Example: For a 2 bit pattern I have 4 states A,B,C,D. I want to cover A>B, A>C, A>D, B>A, B>C, B>D, C>A, C>B, C>D, D>A, D>B and D>C.

Comment: Can't you iterate over all current states and next states, and just discard those where they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having misunderstood the problem the first time, here is another attempt.

So we want to transverse the graph in one go, and we are not allowed to use the same transition twice. The trick is probably to leave a track free to get back to the starting state.

```
states = 4  # Select number of states

path = [0]  # Start in state 0 (must be zero)

def walk(path):
   home_state = path[-1]
   for i in range(home_state + 2, states):
       # We leave a state out that we go to next
       path.append(i)
       path.append(home_state)
   if home_state + 1 < states:
       path.append(home_state + 1)
       walk(path)
       path.append(home_state)

walk(path)
print path
```

should give

```
[0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: I would have to remove duplicates from that list. What I mean by that is, using your logic above will create the transitions as I described in my response under initial question ie.  A>B, A>C, A>D, B>A, B>C, B>D, C>A, C>B, C>D, D>A, D>B and D>C. But this translates to one long transition list of  A>B>A>C>A>D>B>A>B>C>B>D>C>A>C>B>C>D>D>A>D>B>D>C. This introduces duplicates of transitions the first one in this list being B>A.

Comment: Ok, that makes it a bit more complex. I've updated the solution.

Comment: @Malteaser6900 did you get a chance to try out the new solution?

Comment: Yes I did, logic works perfectly for what I need. Thank you. Currently porting from Python to LabVIEW which is the target development environment.